# Xcode add Customise Font will increase the ipa file size

Tags: xcode, fonts, customization, filesize, ipa

I am new to iPhone development. I had follow online instruction to add customise font into xcode project (2 different font type, each file size is 2.4MB). But I was wondering, if I add both the font, will it affect the final product of the application (or ipa) and will it slow down the whole application.

Will it be better to have a lot of images with the font that I wanted (eg. images of button with font on it, etc) into the application or adding the customise font?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No adding custom fonts in your application wouldn't slow its performance. But it will definitely increase the app bundle's size.

Regarding your second question whether to have images instead of custom fonts, I would advise you not to use images. Adding custom fonts is a perfect way to do so.